# Why does my python add function not work for certain integer combinations?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This code adds 2 numbers using bit manipulation.

```
def add(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    sum = a ^ b
    carry = (a & b) << 1
    return add(sum, carry)
```

It will result in a stack overflow calling it with

add(-1,4)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Every time you call `add()` recursively, `a` is a more negative number and `b` is a more positive number. Since integers in python automatically promote to arbitrary length integers when needed, it will never stop executing. If it did not promote to arbitrary length integers I think it would stop executing as you would expect when it overflowed.

Answer (score 4):

The reason that this recurses forever when a is negative is that in Python, integers are arbitrary precision. This means that a negative number effectively has an infinite number of 1 bits in front of it, and it will never overflow. Therefore your algorithm keeps carrying forever, since it never reaches a position with both 0 bits.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because negative numbers are written with a leading ones instead of a leading zeros. In particular `carry` becomes a bigger number in each iteration (and `sum` becomes "negatively" bigger) and the condition `b == 0` is never satisfied resulting in stack overflow (becuase of too deep recursion).